# csrf exception in laravel for payment gateway

Tags: php, paypal

I am learning laravel, I have came across security features like csrf token, which makes our app more secure. Any request outside of app can not make it. I think it is good feature.

But for some work we need to accept request from outside of application such as payment gateway processor. So is there any way we can add exception of payment gateway in laravel app for csrf token?  means the payment gateway site will allowed to post data without sending csrf token .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in app\Http\Middleware you will find the VerifyCrsfToken file. It contains an array

```
protected $except = [
    //
];
```

inside you can place the routes you would like to be ignored and checked for the token. Bare in mind this are post routes in your laravel app. e.g `/auth/login`

Comment: i want to add exception add for site from data will come means certain sites data will be allowed .

Comment: The exception you add is not the sites data is coming from but the route entry point of this data into your application.